# DB connections, how many!

Tags: database, database-connection

Well, I understand this is quite vague to ask how many db write connections should I make.

Still, I'm putting this question here, but in a different way. Lets say I've 10 tables which are independent of each other.
I mean writing into one table does not mandate writing into other. The can be written into any of the tables with equal probabilitites.

What factors should be taken in mind to decide how many write connecttions should I make to a DB. I want to create these connections (connection objects) in memory and use it whenever required.

Comment: question doesn't make alot of sense.

Comment: Read the question 5 times. Cannot process. Vote to close.

Comment: If we don't understand, we should tell the person who posted the question to clarify or update his question. Why should we vote to close ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically it shouldn't matter much as long as you keep your database operations batched together.

Personally I have a `DBRead` function that creates a connection, executes the SQL statement(s), gets a `DataTable` (C#) and closes the connection. It is typically called 3-8 times per page render, which isn't that much considering I make heavy use of AJAX and client-side computing of data (little to no server side paging).

This may be different if the database server is on another computer or even outside your network, as the latency times add up, but typically you should be fine just throwing them away and recreating them.

Comment: @Blindy:Thanks for the nice response. The reason I'm looking to keep the connections as I'm mapping connections with some prepared statements.

Comment: If you mean you're building the `SqlConnection` object (or equivalent in your mystery language), you don't need an open connection for it.

Comment: I'll be creating PGconn* in C using libpq :). I will keep these pointers in memory. If I clear them my prepared statements are also gone.

Comment: Hm in that case I would keep a single connection open, prepare my statements, run them then shut down the connection. You can share a single connection between multiple SQL statements.

Comment: I believe opening multiple connections will better as there would be many many write requests. Moreover, shutdown the connection will lead to deallocation of prepared statements. Isn't it?

Comment: Why would multiple connections be better?

Comment: In case of heavy writes, if one connection is busy serving writing into one table, other connection may be used to write into another table. This is what I think. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: You can write simultaneously to multiple tables with a single connection (even to a single table as long as you access different rows).

Comment: Oh yes you are write. DB server typically can bind itself to only one port. Then why do multiple connections by one process concept exist... ?

Comment: For when multiple clients (programs, computers) want to connect to a single server instance.